# mysql server version 5.7 but if i want to access from console i am happy to help you to get below error

Tags: mysql

Hi I would like to install mysql server version 5.7. If I try to access MYSQL from console it returns the below error.

> mysql: Unknown OS character set 'cp857'. mysql: Switching to the
>   default character set 'latin1'.

Comment: Please, edit your question to add relevant information and a better written english. As of now it makes no sense. We know that english is probably not your language, see if you can get help from someone who does speak english.

Comment: Downvote for stupid title.

Answer (score 1):

Start -> Run -> regedit

Go to [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor]

Add new String Value named: Autorun

Change the value to 'chcp 1252'